ST-LINK v2 got burned when I unplugged it whilst debugging
I'm new at using STM32 I used ST-LINK v2 to program a STM32F103C8T6
that was in a breadboard.
It was working correctly and, while I was debugging the STM32, I unplugged the ST-LINK by mistake and the ST-LINK didn't work again.
Photo of plugged in ST-LINK showing dead LED:

Does anyone know why that happened? What should I do to avoid that again? The breadboard has just LEDs and doesn't have external sources.

What do you mean by "got burned" in your title?  Is there physical damage that you can somehow detect?  From your description, it's really hard to tell if you've damaged something, or if you're having something like a driver problem.

the led did bright again and it doesn't show in pc

Could be some grounding issue. If you power your board  from a separate power source not having a common ground with your ST-Link, then by disconnecting it from each other you might cause the ground pins to get momentarily disconnected first, and then you get two very different voltages across your devices that can very well burn just anything.

Does it smell burnt?

no i upload the picture

Theoretically you might have killed the USB port too. If you are risky, try another one. But first reboot the computer and try with the same one.

Where was your target circuit supplied from? A separate source or the programmer's 3V3 pins?

Please note, this is not an "ST-LINK v2"...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is your ST-LINK v2 clone recognized by your O/S? In Windows Device Manager it would show up as "STM32 STlink" under "Universal Serial Bus Devices". Does the USB port work with something else eg. a mouse? It's possible the port got shorted and shut down. It may restart if you shut down your computer completely and restart it. There might also be an issue with Selective Suspend Settings. Updating firmware may not work (may brick the device) if the clone used a non-ST MCU.

We can't know what happened and what was your setup unless you give the details. For example, was the target board powered from this "ST Link V2 clone" or was the target board separately powered? And like mentioned already, this is not a genuine ST Link V2, this is a cheap clone ripoff so you can't blame ST or ST-Link as a device when it's a device with nothing to do with ST or ST-Link.

ok  im working to drive stepper motor 17hs4401 with driver a4988 at i power the stm32 from pc and  for motor from external source at the first made stm32 give the signals just using  HAL_Delay and the circuit work currectly with the code after that i unplugged the stepper motor and driver i want to work on the timer1 and see its output by led so my circuit was just my pc and st-link and stm32 and like i said when i unplugged the st-link it didnt work again the stm32 it fine and my pc usb port fine also im confused from that(by the way i used STM32 ST-LINK Utility to upload my code)

if you need any additional details i will send it ,i didnt blame any one i just need to avoid this problem again
